# What is the package name for python3 mod_wsgi on Centos 7?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, centos7

I am looking for the python3 version of mod_wsgi for Centos 7. 
I know that for fedora, it is python3-mod_wsgi and ubuntu is libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3. However, I am not able to find the equivalent for Centos 7. I need this package for my django website to run.

Comment: How did you install Python 3?

Comment: compiled from source

Comment: Then a package won't help you. Install mod_wsgi from source as well.

Answer (score 6):

CentOS 7.3 does not have a package of mod_wsgi that is compiled against Python 3.

You can use pip to compile the module yourself:

```
sudo yum install httpd-devel gcc
pip install mod-wsgi
# Becoming root makes it easier to echo to a file in /etc/httpd
sudo -i
echo "LoadModule wsgi_module [path-to-your-virtual-environment]/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py34.cpython-34m.so" > /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-wsgi.conf
exit
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: Don't construct the ``LoadModule`` line yourself. Run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config``. That will tell you correct lines to add. Isn't just the ``LoadModule`` line if you want it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @GrahamDumpleton